# .htaccess rewrite all subdomains to directories of the same name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory for every sub-domain and I want to be able to add more automatically without making a rule for each one.

For example when I go to http://sub.domain.com/index.html it should serve the file /sub/index.html without redirecting the browser.

This is what I've got and it's not working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work on my localhost, but not on my hosted server for some reason. I'll have to contact them.